# Global variable doesn't increase? - also want to save global variable even after app closes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm now trying to learn about global variables that can be used across many different parts of an app.

I'm trying to create a global variable "Quarters" that can be used in any part of my app and that will save whatever the current value is even after the app is closed/quit.

My code below is not increasing my "quarters" variable. It just stays at 0. There are no errors either. I can get it to work if I have the variable inside the struct ContentView, but not if I try to make it a global variable.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyVariables {
    var quarters:Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    //@State private var quarters = 0 - if I point to the variable this way, it works
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("\(MyVariables.quarters)").bold()
        Button(action: {
            MyVariables.quarters += 1
        }) {
            Image("QuarterMachine")
        }
    }
}
}
```

I believe the below two codes can be used to save the variable, but I'm not certain since I can't figure out the above part first.

```
import Foundation

protocol Storage {

    var quarters: Int { get }
    
    func save(quarters: Int)
}
```

And also

```
import Foundation

class LocalStorage: Storage {
    private let quartersKey = "quarters"
    
    func reset() {
        save(quarters: 0)
    }

    var quarters: Int {
        UserDefaults().integer(forKey: quartersKey)
    }

    func save(quarters: Int) {
        UserDefaults().set(quarters, forKey: quartersKey)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a value across all SwiftUI views and save it the same way UserDefaults would do, you can use `@AppStorage`. Just use the same key, `"quarters"` in this example, in the other views to retrieve the saved value.

As for answering your concern on how to update your value elsewhere that on the button tap, you can use a view model to handle all your logic and use `@AppStorage` out of your view.

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @StateObject var viewModel = GameViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("\(viewModel.quarters)")
        .bold()

      Button(action: { viewModel.quarters += 1 }) {
        Image("QuarterMachine")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the view model to handle your logic.

```
final class GameViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @AppStorage("quarters")
  var quarters: Int = .zero

  // You can use this method in your code to increase
  // your quarters value when your game is finished.
  func finishGame() {
    quarters += 1
  }
}
```

Comment: This works! One more question I have. When I'm doing "quarters += 1" in another .swift part of the app, I can get it to work if it's in in a "Button(action: { quarters += 1 })" but if I have just "quarters += 1" then it gives "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" on the VStack line.

Comment: It is because `quarters` is not a view component. It is like a String value, for example, that you would not declare outside of a scope where you can change its value. If you put a String in the same place, you would have this error. Why would you like to put it outside of the `Button(action:title:)`?

Comment: That makes sense. Well, in a previous question I was figuring out navigation views, one of which would go to a game - [this one I found online](https://github.com/caiobzen/2048-swiftui) - what I'm trying to learn now is how to make a game automatically give me quarters after the game is over. I can't quite figure out where I would put it in the linked game, as an example, so I'm trying to figure out what works and doesn't and why.

Comment: I have updated the answer by adding a view model where you could handle the increase of `quarters` elsewhere in your code and adding `@AppStorage` in it.

Comment: I'm getting an odd behavior now when using the AppStorage where when I navigate into either of the two options I have, inside that navigation if I swipe in any direction it immediately exits the navigation and goes back to the main screen. This does not occur if I remove the AppStorage line and var quarters line beneath it. That's with trying it on the linked game above, but I can't figure out what would be causing that since there's no errors and it's only when I add the AppStorage and the var quarters line below it.

Comment: I'm also a little confused on where to put the second bit of code you mentioned. If I'm understanding, I would just use finishGame(), which would call the function to add quarters, but I'm not certain on where to put the final class and other parts.

Comment: This is a new question to be asked on StackOverflow. Please, ask this new question and provide the code that creates this behavior. When you do so, add a comment here with the link to this new question. I would be happy to try to fix your issue and other person in the community could help you out to.

Comment: Thank you @RolandLariotte - Please see the new link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67556849/appstorage-2-times-makes-navigationlinks-exit-upon-single-taps-swipes