# AppStorage 2 times makes navigationlinks exit upon single taps/swipes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When using AppStorage for a global variable, navigationlinks are exited with simple swipe/tap gestures if AppStorage is used 2 times.

When I press one of two buttons to go into one of the two navigationlinks, once inside the NavigationLink, any single tap/swipe immediately exits the NavigationLink.

All I am trying to do is make sure that I can access the global variable "quarters" everywhere in my app - the main screen, the first NavigationLink that gives me quarters, and the second NavigationLink where I use my quarters.

This issue only began when I started using the below two lines of code for the global variable "quarters".

I am also open to any other ways to have a global variable "quarters". This one was suggested in a different question I asked and seems to work really well and easily and simply ... except for this issue.

The code causing the behavior:

```
@AppStorage("quarters")
var quarters: Int = .zero
```

Minimal reproducible code. In the below code, a single button press exits either NavigationLink, but swipes do not exit either NavigationLink.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("quarters")
    var quarters: Int = .zero
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Image("Clouds")
                .overlay(
                VStack(spacing: 30) {
                    Text("\(quarters)").bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    NavigationLink(destination: Menu1(choice: "Menu1")) {
                            Image("Menu")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: Menu2(choice: "Menu2")) {
                            Image("MenuGrey")
                    }
                })
        }
    }
    }

struct Menu1: View {
    @AppStorage("quarters")
    var quarters: Int = .zero
    var choice: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(quarters)")
        Button(action: {
            quarters += 1
        }) {
            Image("Menu")
                .scaleEffect(0.4)
                .frame(width: 305, height: 45)
        }
    }
}

struct Menu2: View {
    @AppStorage("quarters")
    var quarters: Int = .zero
    var choice: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(quarters)")
        Button(action: {
            quarters += 1
        }) {
            Image("MenuGrey")
                .scaleEffect(0.4)
                .frame(width: 305, height: 45)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The main code I want to use it in. In the below code, a single swipe in any direction will exit the NavigationLink. Some button presses cause it to exit, while others don't.

The below code also contains part of [this game I found online](https://github.com/caiobzen/2048-swiftui) - the game has other .swift files as part of the game including swipe gestures, but nothing in those .swift files references any part of the two lines of code in question.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    static let engine = GameEngine()
    static let storage = LocalStorage()
    static let stateTracker = GameStateTracker(initialState: (storage.board ?? engine.blankBoard, storage.score))
    @ObservedObject var viewModel =  GameViewModel(engine, storage: storage, stateTracker: stateTracker)
    @AppStorage("quarters")
    var quarters: Int = .zero
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Image("Clouds")
                .overlay(
                VStack(spacing: 30) {
                    HStack {
                        Image("quarters")
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                        Text("\(quarters)").bold()
                            .frame(width: 65, height: 15)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: ResultView2(choice: "MenuGrey")) {
                            Image("MenuGrey")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: MyContentView(viewModel: viewModel)) {
                        Image("Menu")
                    }
                    //Gain
                    Button(action: {
                        quarters += 1
                    }) {
                        Image("QuarterMachine")
                            .scaleEffect(0.4)
                            .frame(width: 305, height: 45)
                    }
                })
        }
    }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
}

struct MyContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
    @State var showMenu = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
            Header(score: viewModel.state.score, bestScore: viewModel.bestScore, menuAction: {
                self.showMenu.toggle()
            }, undoAction: {
                self.viewModel.undo()
            }, undoEnabled: self.viewModel.isUndoable)
            GoalText()
            Board(board: viewModel.state.board, addedTile: viewModel.addedTile)
            Moves(viewModel.numberOfMoves)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: .zero,
               maxWidth: .infinity,
               minHeight: .zero,
               maxHeight: .infinity,
               alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.gameBackground)
            .background(Menu())
            .background(GameOver())
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
extension MyContentView {
private func Menu() -> some View {
    EmptyView().sheet(isPresented: $showMenu) {
        MenuView(newGameAction: {
            self.viewModel.reset()
            self.showMenu.toggle()
        }, resetScoreAction: {
            self.viewModel.eraseBestScore()
            self.showMenu.toggle()
        })
    }
}

private func GameOver() -> some View {
    EmptyView().sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isGameOver) {
        GameOverView(score: self.viewModel.state.score, moves: self.viewModel.numberOfMoves) {
            self.viewModel.reset()
        }
    }
}
}

struct ResultView2: View {
    @AppStorage("quarters")
    var quarters: Int = .zero
    var choice: String
    var body: some View {
                //Gain
                Button(action: {
                    quarters += 1
                }) {
                    Image("GainQuarters")
                        .scaleEffect(0.4)
                        .frame(width: 305, height: 45)
                }
                //quarters counter
                HStack {
                    Image("quarters")
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    Text(String(quarters)).bold()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 15)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: Below is the GameViewModel code.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import UIKit

class GameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @AppStorage("quarters")
      var quarters: Int = .zero

      @Published var result: Int = .zero

      init() {
        result = quarters // Fetch saved value at startup 
//"'self' used in property access 'quarters' before all stored properties are initialized"
      }
//"Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties"

      // User this method on you Menu view to share the same result.
      func increaseQuarters() {
        result += 1
        quarters = result // Save the new value when result increase
      }
    
//Three below "private(set) var" have a grey notice on the side that say "self.[word] not initialized"
    private(set) var engine: Engine
    private(set) var storage: Storage
    private(set) var stateTracker: StateTracker
  
    @Published var isGameOver = false
    private(set) var addedTile: (Int, Int)? = nil {
        didSet { UIImpactFeedbackGenerator().impactOccurred() }
    }
    private(set) var bestScore: Int = .zero {
        didSet { storage.save(bestScore: bestScore) }
    }
    
    var numberOfMoves: Int {
        return stateTracker.statesCount - 1
    }
    var isUndoable: Bool {
        return stateTracker.isUndoable
    }
//Line below has error "'self.state.board' not initialized" and also for self.state.score
    var state: GameState {
        didSet {
            bestScore = max(bestScore, state.score)
            storage.save(score: state.score)
            isGameOver = engine.isGameOver(state.board)
            storage.save(board: state.board)
        }
    }
    
    init(_ engine: Engine, storage: Storage, stateTracker: StateTracker) {
        self.engine = engine
        self.storage = storage
        self.stateTracker = stateTracker
        self.state = stateTracker.last
        self.bestScore = max(storage.bestScore, storage.score)
    }
    
    func start() {
        if state.board.isMatrixEmpty { reset() }
    }
    
    func addNumber() {
        let result = engine.addNumber(state.board)
        state = stateTracker.updateCurrent(with: result.newBoard)
        addedTile = result.addedTile
    }
    
    func push(_ direction: Direction) {
        let result = engine.push(state.board, to: direction)
        let boardHasChanged = !state.board.isEqual(result.newBoard)
        state = stateTracker.next(with: (result.newBoard, state.score + result.scoredPoints))
        if boardHasChanged {
            addNumber()
        }
    }
    
    func undo() {
        state = stateTracker.undo()
    }
    
    func reset() {
        state = stateTracker.reset(with: (engine.blankBoard, .zero))
        addNumber()
    }
    
    func eraseBestScore() {
        bestScore = .zero
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that you call `@AppStorage` in the `ContentView`, and by using them in `Menu1` and `Menu2`, a pop navigation to the root view is triggered when the value is updated. I don't know if it is a bug from Apple or if it is an expected behavior, but I suggest you to fill a bug report in the FeedbackAssistant.app to let Apple engineers know about it.

To fix your issue, I have created a view model that you will pass between your views and read a new value `result` at startup to retrieve the saved `@AppStorage` value. I added a method to upgrade `result` on the button tap, and then save the new value to `@AppStorage`. By doing so, the NavigationLink behavior you expect is fixed.

This is the new view model that will handle the logic between views and keep track of the `quarters` result:

```
import SwiftUI

final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @AppStorage("quarters")
  var quarters: Int = .zero

  @Published var result: Int = .zero

  init() {
    result = quarters // Fetch saved value at startup
  }

  // User this method on you Menu view to share the same result.
  func increaseQuarters() {
    result += 1
    quarters = result // Save the new value when result increase
  }
}
```

This is the views you are using with the logic that fixes your issue. Note that I added a `.resizable()` under your image for them to use the provided frame:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel() // Use @StateObject, not @ObservedObject

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Image("Clouds")
        .overlay(
          VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("\(viewModel.result)") // Use "result" instead of "quarters" from viewModel.
              .bold()
              .foregroundColor(.white)

            NavigationLink(destination: Menu1(viewModel: viewModel)) {
              Image("Menu")
            }

            NavigationLink(destination: Menu2(viewModel: viewModel)) {
              Image("MenuGrey")
            }
          })
    }
  }
}

struct Menu1: View {

  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel // @ObservedObject must be used this way

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 32) {
      Text("\(viewModel.result)")  // Use "result" instead of "quarters" from viewModel.

      Button(action: { viewModel.increaseQuarters() }) {
        Image("Menu")
          .resizable() // Use Resizable on image when modifying them
          .scaleEffect(0.4)
          .frame(width: 305, height: 45)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Menu2: View {

  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel // @ObservedObject must be used this way

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 32) {
      Text("\(viewModel.result)")  // Use "result" instead of "quarters" from viewModel.

      Button(action: { viewModel.increaseQuarters() }) {
        Image("MenuGrey")
          .resizable()  // User Resizable on image when modifying them
          .scaleEffect(0.4)
          .frame(width: 305, height: 45)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding where the first section of code goes. I tried putting it in its own .swift file in the app, but then I get the error "Cannot find 'ContentViewModel' in scope" on each of the lines that have "StateObject ..." and the two "ObservedObject" for the navigation links. However, if I put the first section of code at the top of the main block of code, then it opens up a very large number off errors throughout the entire code.

Comment: Also, in the navigationlink for the game there is already a line for "ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel", so would adding "ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel" create an error? It seems like it is.

Comment: Tinkering with the code a little bit here and there, I got it to work with the first section of code at the very top of the main code (the last section of code from my question). Now, the only issue is the thing I noted above - both of the "ObservedObject var viewModel:" in the one navigationlink. It's giving the error "Cannot convert value of type 'ContentViewModel' to expected argument type 'GameViewModel'" and is the only remaining error it's giving to be able to test it all out.

Comment: It is because I gave you an example of how to make it work with the first part of the code. You have to use the logic inside the `ContentViewModel` to your `GameViewModel`. The second part of the code you provided does not compile for me, and you have to make it work on your project by understanding the solution I have shared with you. Do not use`@ObservedObject` as the first element. Look how I use first `@StateObject` and then pass is around using `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding, and I appreciate the info, when you say "use the logic inside the ContentViewModel", I assume you're meaning the first part of your code - the code inside the ContentViewModel. When you say "to your GameViewModel", could you clarify what you mean? Does that mean I need to put the contents of the "GameViewModel" into the ContentViewModel or vice versa?

Comment: You have to update the GameViewModel with the content inside the ContentViewModel. The code I provided works, but it is not made for your second example. So you have to use the logic I show you and implement it in your project.

Comment: I'm getting two errors when entering your first code into the GameViewModel, but it seems I just need to "initialize". The first is "'self' used in property access 'quarters' before all stored properties are initialized" on the line with "result = quarters" and the second is "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" on the line right below that. I know I need to initialize 4 lines in particular because it highlights them in grey, but I don't know how to do that because just putting init() { } isn't right. I'm adding the code to the above.

Comment: You already have an initializer in your code. You don’t need two of them. Just put ´result = quarters´ in ´ init(_ engine: Engine, storage: Storage, stateTracker: StateTracker)´.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232486/discussion-between-sunit1-and-roland-lariotte).

Comment: I'm getting a crash error even though the build is successful. When running it, the screen is just black and blank. I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560232/could-not-cast-value-of-type-test-engine-protocol-0x1c31e6650-to-test-engin